# How i can to change the size of a form c# without losing the structure

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I made a virtual keyboard in C# Visual Studio, but I have problems when I try to change the dimensions.

This is the virtual keyboard: 
[image: keyboard]

and this is when I try to change the dimensions:
[image: altered keyboard]

I lose the buttons. I found a tutorial where he uses a rectangle.

In [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA8yQ.png) is the "main" function, and after I called this function for every button from list (I make a list with all the buttons), I lose all the buttons. Only shift/caps remain because they are special characters.

Comment: Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51174617/edit) to include your code formatted using markdown (the button marked `{}`) instead of an image. Also be sure to include all relevant code as part of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "Only shift/caps remain because they are special characters."  make all the keys special then?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to anchor the buttons and enable auto size then set the AutoSize mode to grow and shrink.

If all else fails, writing a function to change the font of each button to change down in size according to the size of the form is your only option.

What the problem most likely is is that the font sizes for the individual keys is too big and when you re-scale the keyboard the font doesn't change to compensate for the scaling down in buttons.

(EDIT) 
Also, next time you make a post on these forums try to keep up with the formatting and try to use more accurate descriptions of the problem as well as the properties of the buttons because all of my possible solutions are just going off a whim based on prior experience. Thanks

(EDIT EDIT)
Ok I just saw the resizeControl method, I didnt see that before, however, my previous edit still applies. Properties for the buttons would be much appreciated to help answer your question. Also, try to edit the image to instead of being an image, just use the markup language like so:

```
//Like this
```

To make it easier for us to use and help debug, if you need to know how, just add 4 spaces before your code. Again, thanks